# Help with formula for validation rule on user fields

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to create a validation rule requiring 3 fields to be populated for 3 profiles.  Here is what i have so far. I gave up after continued syntax errors.  I need both Zone Approver Fields and the Sales Report Label field populated for these 3 profiles.  The zone approver fields are type "hierarchy" and the Sales Report Label field is a picklist.  Thank you in advance!

```
AND(OR(ProfileId ="00e30000001iKyY",ProfileId="00e30000001iKzE",ProfileId="00e30000001iL0B"), 
OR(
LEN(Zone_1_Approver__r.Id)=0),
LEN(Zone_2_Approver__r.Id)=0),
Text(Sales_Report_Label__c)= ""))
```

Comment: What were the syntax errors? Other users might have trouble reproducing them exactly

Comment: They kept changing with every update.  I received extra "," here: LEN(Zone_2_Approver__r.Id)=0),   which i know i need. Then i would remove it and get a different error missing ")".  Also received "extra LEN".  Basically every time i changed something that errored i would get a different error.

Answer (score 6):

If your'e trying to check for null values you need to wrap your field with ISBLANK

```
AND(OR( $Profile.Name ="profile1",$Profile.Name="profile2",$Profile.Name="profile3"), 
   OR(
   ISBLANK(Zone_1_Approver__c),
   ISBLANK(Zone_2_Approver__c),
   ISBLANK(Text(Sales_Report_Label__c))))
```

As a best practice try using profile name instead of hard coded Id's

Comment: Just so you know, you have the option to "accept" this answer to indicate it solved your issue. That gives you and him both a small reputation bump and visually highlights the question as resolved. It's always up to you to accept or not.

Answer (score 3):

As written, the formula simply has unbalanced parentheses. Treat formulas like algebra, or Excel formulas - you always must balance parentheses and separate formula parameters with commas.

```
AND(
    OR(ProfileId ="00e30000001iKyY",ProfileId="00e30000001iKzE",ProfileId="00e30000001iL0B"), 
    OR(
        LEN(Zone_1_Approver__r.Id)=0), // <--- extra parenthesis
        LEN(Zone_2_Approver__r.Id)=0), // <--- extra parenthesis
        Text(Sales_Report_Label__c) = ""
    )
)
```

You should also, however, see @codeyinthecloud's answer. It's best practice to use `ISBLANK()` on the relationship field itself rather than relying on behavior when you refer across a non-populated relationship. Additionally, it would be best to use a Custom Permission rather than hard-coding profile references.